# My quickSort is not working correctly. What did I do wrong?

Tags: c

My QuickSort doesn't sort. I don't understand why. When I did my sort twice, it sorted correctly, but if we use quicksort two times—it's not quicksort.

---

My task is to write a universal quick-sort function so that it sorts arrays of any type. In the function, we are given a pointer to a string for sorting, the length of the string, the size of one element and the comparison function.

My compare func:

```
int icmp(void* x, void* y)
{
    int a = *(int*)x;
    int b = *(int*)y;
    if (a > b) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (a < b) {
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

My swap func:

```
void swapper(void* x, void* y, size_t size)
{
    char* a = NULL;
    if ((a = (char*)malloc(size * sizeof(char*))) == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        a[i] = *((char*)x + i * sizeof(char*));
    }
    *(char*)x = *(char*)y;
    *(char*)y = *a;
}
```

My sort func:

```
void my_qsort(const void* ptr, size_t count, size_t size, int (*cmp)(const void*, const void*))
{
    sort(ptr, 0, count - 1, size, cmp);
}

void sort(const void* ptr, int low, int high, size_t size, int (*cmp)(const void*, const void*))
{
    int i = low;
    int j = high;
    char* mid = (char*)ptr + ((i + j) / 2) * size;
    while (i <= j)
    {
        while ((cmp((char*)ptr + i * size, mid) == -1)) {
            i++;
        }
        while (cmp((char*)ptr + j * size, mid) == 1) {
            j--;
        }
        if (i <= j) {
            swapper((char*)ptr + i * size, (char*)ptr + j * size, size);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    if (j > low) {
        sort(ptr, low, j, size, cmp);
    }
    if (i < high) {
        sort(ptr, i, high, size, cmp);
    }
}
```

1)Input ptr:83 21 52 10 49 22 21 34 51 51

Output ptr:10 21 21 22 34 49 51 52 51 83

2)Input ptr:59 4 47 79 9 44 5 78 40 19

Output ptr:4 5 9 19 40 44 47 59 78 79

3)Input ptr:13 80 97 73 14 17 32 26 92 90

Output ptr:13 14 73 17 26 32 80 90 92 97

Comment: What were you actually getting as a result, instead of a sorted list?

Comment: @OrdoFlammae , I got a sorted list, but not completely. For example, I show you part of an array: (correct sort), 85, 46, 52, 92, 93, (and also correct sort).

Comment: Could you post your testing code? We need a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @SkivHisink The `swapper` function copies only the first byte at the end. This is likely the source of your problem. Moreover, you allocate memory but never deallocate it. To avoid memory allocation, I suggest to swap byte by byte.

Comment: @OrdoFlammae, I did it(but in a simple way).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A part of the problem comes from the `swapper` function that only copies the first byte. You can rewrite the function as:

```
void swapper(void* x, void* y, size_t size)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        char tmp = ((char*)x)[i];
        ((char*)x)[i] = ((char*)y)[i];
        ((char*)y)[i] = tmp;
    }
}
```

This avoid memory allocation. Note: The memory was not deallocated before leaving the function, so it also created a memory leak.

The second part of the problem is the you change the pivot while you are iterating. A simple way to implement it is using the algorithm found [here](https://beginnersbook.com/2015/02/quicksort-program-in-c/):

```
void sort(const void* ptr, int low, int high, size_t size, int (*cmp)(const void*, const void*))
{
    int i = low;
    int j = high;
    char* pivot = (char*)ptr + low * size;
    while (i < j)
    {
        while ((cmp((char*)ptr + i * size, pivot) <= 0)) {
            i++;
        }
        while (cmp((char*)ptr + j * size, pivot) > 0) {
            j--;
        }
        if (i < j) {
            swapper((char*)ptr + i * size, (char*)ptr + j * size, size);
        }
    }
    swapper(pivot, (char*)ptr + j * size, size);
    if (j-1 > low) {
        sort(ptr, low, j-1, size, cmp);
    }
    if (j+1 < high) {
        sort(ptr, j+1, high, size, cmp);
    }
}
```